# ps command the program name

Tags: linux, ps

Is there a way to display the program name? Like in windows when you open the task manager, it will display the program name instead of the directory under COMMAND

EDIT:
Commands I used so far

```
ps aux | grep chromium
```

Output under COMMAND:

```
/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser
```

EDIT 2:
I found a command called `top` and under COMMAND it shows the program name, is there a way doing the same in `ps`?

Comment: Since top's output is suitable for you, can you try `ps -e | grep chromium` ?

Answer (score 2):

Try `pgrep -l chromium` command. It will give you PID and command name. If you want to have more detailed output you can use `pgrep` and `for` loop with `ps` command:

```
for PROC in $(pgrep chromium)
do
    ps -p $PROC -o pid,uid,gid,time,ucmd
done
```

Make sure you use `ucmd` not `cmd` because `cmd` will give you full path instead of executable name. Of course you can modify output by changing `-o` options. You can find all available fields in `man ps` under section `STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command,

```
ps aux | grep < program name>
```

E.g.:

```
ps aux | grep httpd
```

Comment: i tried that and i get a directory like `/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser` I want to get the program name like `chromium`

Comment: @JayLee There is no way for `ps` to figure out that a process is running a program called something special other than what the executable file is called.

Comment: @Kusalananda That's what i want, the executable file, i was using an example like chromium-browser, in `ps` it shows the directory under COMMAND, but in `top` it shows the executable file, how do i show the executable file in `ps`

Comment: @JayLee `/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser ` is an executable file. `/usr/lib/chromium-browser/` is a directory. `/usr/bin/chromium-browser` is a shell script that `exec`s `/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser`, so that's the executable associated with that process.